# angular js and isotopes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-isotope

I want to use angular js and isotopes. I have created some jsFiddle for it and link for that filddle is given below.

http://jsfiddle.net/shardulpendse/NTsZx/118/

I have created angular directive

```
app.directive('myDir', function ()
{
 scope: {
itemArr =""//accepting the array
},
template://template where i have use ng-repeat on div. 
//When I click on a particular div that div height should be expanded. 
//If I clicked on another div then previously expanded dive height its height should back to normal and this div height should be expanded
});
```

When I click on the cell(1). that item should get expand and other items should re layout themselves. But i am not able to do so. Can any one help doing this. Please

Comment: can any body please help me in doing this stuff. I m struggling a bit. Can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

It works if you `$watch` the items and call isotope whenever they get updated: http://jsfiddle.net/c3mLpr77/

```
scope.$watch("itemArr", function(){
       var _parentNode = $('#container');
       _parentNode.isotope({
            layoutMode : 'fitColumns',
            resizesContainer : false,
            sortBy : 'fitOrder'
       });
}, true);
```

I also implemented a native AngularJS version of isotope that takes off a lot of issues related to having AngularJS and jQuery play well together: http://tristanguigue.github.io/angular-dynamic-layout/

Comment: Sorry for a late reply. Thank You